# Is there something like Python's 'with' in C#?

Tags: c#, python, exception

Python has a nice keyword since 2.6 called **with**. Is there something similar in C#?

Answer (score 23):

The equivalent is the `using` statement

An example would be

```
  using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
  {
    DoSomethingWith(reader);
  }
```

The restriction is that the type of the variable scoped by the using clause must implement `IDisposable` and it is its `Dispose()` method that gets called on exit from the associated code block.

Answer (score 9):

C# has the `using` statement, as mentioned in another answer and documented here:

- [using Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx)

However, it's **not equivalent** to Python's `with` statement, in that there is no analog of the `__enter__` method.

In C#:

```
using (var foo = new Foo()) {

    // ...

    // foo.Dispose() is called on exiting the block
}
```

In Python:

```
with Foo() as foo:
    # foo.__enter__() called on entering the block

    # ...

    # foo.__exit__() called on exiting the block
```

More on the `with` statement here:

- http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is one additional minor difference using `using` that others didn't mention.

C#'s `using` is meant to clean up "unmanaged resources" and while it's guaranteed will be called/disposed, its order / when it will be called isn't necessarily guaranteed.

So if you planned on Open/closing stuff in the right order in which they got called, you might be out of luck using `using`.

**Source:** [Dispose of objects in reverse order of creation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306599/dispose-of-objects-in-reverse-order-of-creation/10306626#10306626)

Comment: The link you provide doesn't support your claim about `using` not guaranteeing when disposal happens.

Comment: The [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) say `using` is translated to a try-finally that calls `Dispose` in the `finally`, making cleanup deterministic.