# How does user1 (admin) submit presence subscription request from user2 to user 3

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I hope it is possible because I couldn't find it anywhere on the web or in the XMPP/ejabberd docs:
I run ejabberd and would like the ability for user1 (an administrator account) to be able to push a presence subscription request to user3 that appears to have come from user2. For security reasons I would have user1 be designated as a user with privileges to do this.
Is this possible and can you give me any pointers?

Comment: This should be possible if you write a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

It can be managed through Ejabberd database.

Configure the Ejabberd to communicate with the external database (mysql or `mssql`).

Create the dynamic web page in any server-side prog. to login with admin on ejabberd and change the rosterusers table in the external database.

By default Ejabberd uses `mnesia` database. You can configure it with `mssql` or `mysql`.

For mssql :

http://www.ejabberd.im/mssql